# User Record and Contact Record - Documentation?

Tags: administration, account, contact, user

**What automation is there for a User record in regards to a linked Contact (and Account)?**   In fact, what use is the Contact lookup on User and where is it relevant?

I cannot find any relevant documentation on this relationship - **User records having a lookup to Contact** (and therefore, the Reports for Users having access to Contact and Account fields).

I see in an Org I'm currently helping configure that nothing is automatically being created (Contacts/Accounts) when Users are created, so... I'm curious what it's purpose is (or more specifically, when is User associated with a Contact?  Only manually?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

User records can only be linked to a Contact (which must be linked to an Account) in the case of Portal User.

**Details**

Take a look at the `User` object documentation for the **[`ContactId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)** field in the `SOAP API Developer Guide`:

> **Field**
> ContactId
>
> **Type**
> reference
>
> **Properties**
> Create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
>
> **Description**
> ID of the Contact associated with this account. The contact must have a value in the AccountId field or an error occurs.

Note, however, that if you try to create an otherwise valid `User` record with the `ContactId` field populated, you will get this error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, only portal users can be associated to a contact: []

So, you can only specify a `ContactId` for a portal user, and the associated `Contact` must also be related to an `Account`.

Comment: Neat.  Nothing on the field itself to tell you this.  Help link on the field leads to a generic help page.  Soooo insightful   ;-)   Thanks for the heads up.  Portal users only.   Wish I could hide or otherwise disassociate this in cases where we WILL NOT be using Portal users.  (shrug)  Oh well.